# Telethon Error: Can not add user to group using AddChatUserRequest(), Invalid object ID for a chat

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telethon

I tried to use the telethon to develop a telegram bot, when I used AddChatUserRequest to add a user to a group

```
client(AddChatUserRequest(1168070860, user.id, fwd_limit=10))
```

I met the error:

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChatIdInvalidError: Invalid object ID for
>   a chat. Make sure to pass the right types, for instance making sure
>   that the request is designed for chats (not channels/megagroups) or
>   otherwise look for a different one more suited\nAn example working
>   with a megagroup and AddChatUserRequest, it will fail because
>   megagroups are channels. Use InviteToChannelRequest instead (caused by
>   AddChatUserRequest)

I used these code to get the group's information:

```
chats = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=None,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=200,
             hash = 0
         )).chats

groups = []
for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup == True:
            groups.append(chat)
            print(chat.title,chat.id)
    except:
        continue
```

And here's the group's information that I tried to add user:

```
Channel(left=False, id=1168070860, banned_rights=None, title='ruby and his friends', version=0, verified=False, signatures=False, broadcast=False, participants_count=None, creator=True, has_geo=False, photo=ChatPhoto(dc_id=1, photo_small=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(local_id=270793, volume_id=806122192), photo_big=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(local_id=270795, volume_id=806122192)), username='lanlugroup', megagroup=True, restricted=False, default_banned_rights=ChatBannedRights(change_info=True, until_date=datetime.datetime(2038, 1, 19, 3, 14, 7, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), send_inline=False, invite_users=False, pin_messages=True, send_media=False, send_gifs=False, send_games=False, embed_links=False, send_stickers=False, send_messages=False, view_messages=False, send_polls=False), restriction_reason=None, min=False, has_link=False, scam=False, date=datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 12, 44, 47, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), admin_rights=None, access_hash=-5901560198799322202)
```

I used the id 1168070860 as the chat_id in AddChatUserRequest

(BTW, I login with the phone number as a normal user, not as a bot)

Answer (score 1):

Use InviteToChannelRequest instead. My solution:

```
chat_id = "mychatid"
users = ['UserName']

response = client.invoke(ResolveUsernameRequest(chat_id))

target_group_entity = InputPeerChannel(response.chats[0].id, response.chats[0].access_hash)

try:
    res = client(InviteToChannelRequest(channel=target_group_entity, users=users ))
except Exception as e:
    print("spam protection: " + e.message + ": " + str(e))
```